# Как заставить Tasksheduler выполнить работу и перейти в статус "ready", при том что работа которую он выполняет должна выполняться дальше?

Tags: windows, bat, task

OC: Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise

Я поставил в Tasksheduler выполнение ежедневного старта БД influxDB. При этом task стартуеться и висит в статусе "running". есть ли возможность закончить таск, но чтобы при этом осталась работать БД.
Батник старта:

```
title influxDB
call %influx% >>%LOGFILE_NAME% 2>>&1
echo TASK ENDED >>%LOGFILE_NAME% 2>>&1
```

перед этим присутствует инициализация имени лог фала, но она, думаю, не нужна.

Comment: В таске стартуй батник, который запустит твой батник в новом процессе командного интертрепатора. Шедулер отслеживает только порождённый им процесс, но не его дочек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените команду call на команду start. Но будьте внимательнее - выполнение пакетного файла продолжится сразу же, что может привести к ошибкам или ввести в заблуждение.

Возможно, имеет смысл оставить команду `start` последней в пакетном файле. А возможно, имеет смысл создать второй пакетный файл, который будет запускать командой start первый.

---

PS Но, вообще говоря, вы делаете что-то не то. Планировщик задач не предназначен для запуска постоянно работающих программ. Для этих целей лучше подходят системные службы.